# Want to print maxm entry of every email against it in another column

Tags: python, shell, csv, large-files

I have a huge File around 2 GB having more then 20million rows

what i want is

Input File will be like this

```
07.SHEKHAR@GMAIL.COM,1
07SHIBAJI@GMAIL.COM,1
07.SHINDE@GMAIL.COM,1
07.SHINDE@GMAIL.COM,2
07.SHINDE@GMAIL.COM,3
07.SHINDE@GMAIL.COM,4
07.SHINDE@GMAIL.COM,5
07.SHINDE@GMAIL.COM,6
07.SHINDE@GMAIL.COM,7
07.SHOBHIT@GMAIL.COM,1
07SKERCH@RUSKIN.AC.UK,1
07SONIA@GMAIL.COM,1
07SONIA@GMAIL.COM,2
07SONIA@GMAIL.COM,3
07SRAM@GMAIL.COM,1
07SRAM@GMAIL.COM,2
07.SUMANTA@GMAIL.COM,1
07SUPRIYO@GMAIL.COM,1
07SUPRIYO@GMAIL.COM,2
07SUPRIYO@GMAIL.COM,3
07.SUSHMA@GMAIL.COM,1
07.SWETA@GMAIL.COM,1
07.SWETA@GMAIL.COM,2
07.SWETA@GMAIL.COM,3
07.TEENA@GMAIL.COM,1
07.TEENA@GMAIL.COM,2
07.UDAY@GMAIL.COM,1
07.UMESH@GMAIL.COM,1
07VAISHALISINGH@GMAIL.COM,1
07.VISHAL@GMAIL.COM,1,1
07.VISHAL@GMAIL.COM,2
07.VISHAL@GMAIL.COM,3
07.VISHAL@GMAIL.COM,4
07.VISHAL@GMAIL.COM,5
07.VISHAL@GMAIL.COM,6
07.VISHAL@GMAIL.COM,7
07.YASH@GMAIL.COM,1
07.YASH@GMAIL.COM,2
07.YASH@GMAIL.COM,3
07.YASH@GMAIL.COM,4
```

Output File Needed:-

```
07.SHEKHAR@GMAIL.COM,1,1
07SHIBAJI@GMAIL.COM,1,1
07.SHINDE@GMAIL.COM,1,7
07.SHINDE@GMAIL.COM,2,7
07.SHINDE@GMAIL.COM,3,7
07.SHINDE@GMAIL.COM,4,7
07.SHINDE@GMAIL.COM,5,7
07.SHINDE@GMAIL.COM,6,7
07.SHINDE@GMAIL.COM,7,7
07.SHOBHIT@GMAIL.COM,1,1
07SKERCH@RUSKIN.AC.UK,1,1
07SONIA@GMAIL.COM,1,3
07SONIA@GMAIL.COM,2,3
07SONIA@GMAIL.COM,3,3
07SRAM@GMAIL.COM,1,2
07SRAM@GMAIL.COM,2,2
07.SUMANTA@GMAIL.COM,1,1
07SUPRIYO@GMAIL.COM,1,3
07SUPRIYO@GMAIL.COM,2,3
07SUPRIYO@GMAIL.COM,3,3
07.SUSHMA@GMAIL.COM,1,1
07.SWETA@GMAIL.COM,1,3
07.SWETA@GMAIL.COM,2,3
07.SWETA@GMAIL.COM,3,3
07.TEENA@GMAIL.COM,1,2
07.TEENA@GMAIL.COM,2,2
07.UDAY@GMAIL.COM,1,1
07.UMESH@GMAIL.COM,1,1
07VAISHALISINGH@GMAIL.COM,1,1
07.VISHAL@GMAIL.COM,1,7
07.VISHAL@GMAIL.COM,2,7
07.VISHAL@GMAIL.COM,3,7
07.VISHAL@GMAIL.COM,4,7
07.VISHAL@GMAIL.COM,5,7
07.VISHAL@GMAIL.COM,6,7
07.VISHAL@GMAIL.COM,7,7
07.YASH@GMAIL.COM,1,4
07.YASH@GMAIL.COM,2,4
07.YASH@GMAIL.COM,3,4
07.YASH@GMAIL.COM,4,4
```

i,e 1 more column containing maximum no of entries corresponding to a particular email in each column so that every row now contains maximum occurence of each email.
I am looking for a feasible soln for such a large file preferably in python or shell script and complexity of O(n) or O(nlogn)
O(n**2) wont do in this case

Comment: Your input file looks sorted, is that the case? or can it be sorted within your time constraint (e.g. by the unix sort tool, which iirc uses merge sort at n*log(n) complexity)?  Working with a sorted file makes this much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try a python script since you may be more familiar with that language, doesn't require huge memory or hard disk space. Tested on Python 2.7 and 3.2

```
#!/usr/bin/python
email = "" # Initialize the email
count = 0  # and counter
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input("word.txt"): # Interator: process a line at a time
  myArr = line.split(",")
  if (email != myArr[0]): # New email; print and reset count, email
    for n in range(0,count):
      print email + "," + str(n+1) + "," + str(count)
    email = myArr[0]
    count = 1  
  else: # Same email, increment count
    count = count + 1

# Print the final email
for n in range(0,count):
  print email + "," + str(n+1) + "," + str(count)
```

Anyone want to try an `awk` script?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to have a third column containing the maximun value of the second column for each mail.

I that case, I would use a map to store the maximun second column value found for each mail:

Pseudo code:

1. Create a empty map where mail strings are the keys set -> M
2. For each line (l) of the input file:

   1. if (l.mail not in M) OR (l.mail in M AND l.secondColumn > M[l.mail].secondColumn) Then: l.thirdColumn = l.secondColunn AND M[l.mail] = l;
3. Create a new file -> fOut
4. Iterate over the map entries (for each map entry):

   1. Append M[entry] to fOut.

Comment: thanks for the reply but i dont think such a huge map cant reside in memory at the same time so i dont think this soln is feasible

Comment: If your problem is memory but you have plenty of disk space and time then you could try to split your input file into files small enought to be stored in your memory. One option could be translating the map structure into files so each file contains the information relative to one and only one mail match:
    grep "07.SHEKHAR@GMAIL.COM" input.txt > fileOf07.SHEKHAR@GMAIL.COM.tzt