# Pandas HDFStore unload dataframe from memory

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, pytables, hdfstore

OK I am experimenting with pandas to load around a 30GB csv file with 40 million+ rows and 150+ columns in to HDFStore. The majority of the columns are strings, followed by numerical and dates.

I have never really used numpy, pandas or pytables before but have played around with data frames in R.

I am currently just storing a sample file of around 20000 rows in to HDFStore. When I try to read the table from HDFStore the table is loaded to memory and memory usage goes up by ~100MB

```
f=HDFStore('myfile.h5')
g=f['df']
```

Then I delete the variable containing the DataFrame:

```
del g
```

At the point the memory usage decreases by about 5MB

If I again load the data into g using `g=f['df']`, the memory usage shoots up another 100MB

Cleanup only happens when I actually close the window.

The way the data is organized, I am probably going to divide the data into individual tables with the max table size around 1GB which can fit into memory and then use it one at a time. However, this approach will not work if I am not able to clear memory.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: You've read this? (Shows a function for taking in data from csv file and creating a store by chunks, with date parsing as well): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110252/need-to-compare-very-large-files-around-1-5gb-in-python/16110391#16110391

Comment: You need to close the store. There is extensive documentation of using ``HDFStore`` [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#hdf5-pytables)

Comment: any updates on this? I am experiencing the same issue. and ``f.close()`` doesn't alter the memory use in my case

Answer (score 3):

To answer on the second point of OP's question ("how to free memory")

**Short answer**

Closing the store and deleting the selected dataframe does not work, however I found a call to `gc.collect()` clears up memory well after you delete the dataframe.

**Example**

In the example below, memory is cleaned automatically as expected:

```
data=numpy.random.rand(10000,1000)         # memory up by 78MB
df=pandas.DataFrame(data)                  # memory up by 1 MB

store = pandas.HDFStore('test.h5')         # memory up by 3 MB
store.append('df', df)                     # memory up by 9 MB (why?!?!)

del data                                   # no change in memory
del df                                     # memory down by 78 MB

store.close()                              # no change in memory
gc.collect()                               # no change in memory (1)
```

(1) the store is still in memory, albeit closed

Now suppose we continue from above and reopen `store` as per below. Memory is cleaned **only after** gc.collect() is called:

```
store = pandas.HDFStore('test.h5')         # no change in memory (2) 
df = store.select('df')                    # memory up by 158MB ?! (3)
del df                                     # no change in memory
store.close()                              # no change in memory
gc.collect()                               # memory down by 158 MB (4)
```

(2) the store never left, (3) I have read that selection of a table migth take up as much as 3x the sixe of the table, (4) the store is still there

Finally I also tried to do a `.copy()` of the df on open (`df = store.select('df')`). **Do not** do this, it creates a monster in memory that cannot be garbage-collected afterwards.

**Final question**
If a DF in memory is 100MB, I understand it might occupy 2-3x size in memory while loading but why does it *stay* at 200MB in memory after I select it from an HDFStore and close the store?