# Insert a date in a column using awk

Tags: bash, date, awk

I'm trying to format a date in a column of a csv.

The input is something like: `28 April 1966`

And I'd like this output: `1966-04-28`

which can be obtain with this code:

```
date -d "28 April 1966" +%F
```

So now I thought of mixing awk and this code to format the entire column but I can't find out how.

Edit :

Example of input : (separators "|" are in fact tabs)

```
1 | 28 April 1966
2 | null
3 | null
4 | 30 June 1987
```

Expected output :

```
1 | 1966-04-28
2 | null
3 | null
4 | 30 June 1987
```

Comment: mmm yes, it is possible with awk. But how does your input file look like? `mktime` can help, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/6820700/1983854

Comment: An other scripting language should be ok. I just need to format this correctly in order to import in a DB

Comment: PLEASE note that i have to run that on billions of entries...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way is

```
awk -F '\\| ' -v OFS='| ' '{ cmd = "date -d \"" $3 "\" +%F 2> /dev/null"; cmd | getline $3; close(cmd) } 1' filename
```

That is:

```
{
  cmd = "date -d \"" $3 "\" +%F 2> /dev/null"  # build shell command
  cmd | getline $3                             # run, capture output
  close(cmd)                                   # close pipe
}
1                                              # print
```

This works because `date` doesn't print anything to its stdout if the date is invalid, so the `getline` fails and `$3` is not changed.

Caveats to consider:

1. For very large files, this will spawn a lot of shells and processes in those shells (one each per line). This can become a noticeable performance drag.
2. **Be wary of code injection.** If the CSV file comes from an untrustworthy source, this approach is difficult to defend against an attacker, and you're probably better off going the long way around, parsing the date manually with gawk's `mktime` and `strftime`.

**EDIT re: comment:** To use tabs as delimiters, the command can be changed to

```
awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' '{ cmd = "date -d \"" $3 "\" +%F 2> /dev/null"; cmd | getline $3; close(cmd) } 1' filename
```

**EDIT re: comment 2:** If performance is a worry, as it appears to be, spawning processes for every line is not a good approach. In that case, you'll have to do the parsing manually. For example:

```
BEGIN {
  OFS = FS

  m["January"  ] =  1
  m["February" ] =  2
  m["March"    ] =  3
  m["April"    ] =  4
  m["May"      ] =  5
  m["June"     ] =  6
  m["July"     ] =  7
  m["August"   ] =  8
  m["September"] =  9
  m["October"  ] = 10
  m["November" ] = 11
  m["December" ] = 12
}

$3 !~ /null/ {
  split($3, a, " ")
  $3 = sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d", a[3], m[a[2]], a[1])
}
1
```

Put that in a file, say `foo.awk`, and run `awk -F '\t' -f foo.awk filename.csv`.

Comment: I'd delete my answer as it's identical to yours, but i've already deleted too many today from this happening :(

Comment: Ugh, you're really too fast... what is close(cmd) useful for? date exits anyway, doesn't it?

Comment: Many thanks for rapid answer ;)
Just one thing : I don't have " | " as a separator but " \t " (tabs). Could you please edit ?? :D

Comment: @Camusensei it closes the pipe that is opened with getline.

Comment: @Camusensei The pipes persist between records, so if you open a pipe for every line but never close them, you run the risk of running out of file descriptors. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Close-Files-And-Pipes.html

Comment: @Piloumpicou Just setting `FS` and `OFS` to `\t` should do it. See edit.

Comment: @Wintermute Ok, i finally got it and it works well ! Many thanks.... Now the problem is that the csv has a few billion of entries... Do you see how we could optimise that ??

Comment: @Piloumpicou I put up a way to keep the whole thing in awk, which should make it much faster. Mind you, for a few billion lines I do have to ask: Have you considered using a database instead of flat files?

Comment: I was going to go with the array-based approach but I really couldn't be bothered! I guess it will be faster than my approach which uses date parsing though, so +1 for that.

Comment: @Wintermute Yeeey you're awsome, it perfectly works and it's very fast (a few ms for 100 entries). Well I precisely need this format to enter the csv in my DB...Does it sounds absurd?

Comment: instead of creating the array that way you can just use split `split("January February...December",m)`

Comment: @JID That would give me an array that maps the other way around (I could get `"February"` as `m[2]`, not `2` as `m["February"]`). I could invert such an array with a loop, but at that point I'm not convinced that it is prettier than the code in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should work with your given input

```
awk -F'\\|' -vOFS="|" '!/null/{cmd="date -d \""$3"\" +%F";cmd | getline $3;close(cmd)}1' file
```

#### Output

```
| 1 |1966-04-28
| 2 | null
| 3 | null
| 4 |1987-06-30
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a language that supports parsing dates, like perl:

```
$ cat file
1       28 April 1966
2       null
3       null
4       30 June 1987
$ perl -F'\t' -MTime::Piece -lane 'print "$F[0]\t", 
  $F[1] eq "null" ? $F[1] : Time::Piece->strptime($F[1], "%d %B %Y")->strftime("%F")' file
1       1966-04-28
2       null
3       null
4       1987-06-30
```

The `Time::Piece` core module allows you to parse and format dates, using the standard format specifiers of `strftime`. This solution splits the input on a tab character and modifies the format if the second field is not "null".

This approach will be much faster than using `system` calls or invoking subprocesses, as everything is done in native perl.

Comment: I always like solutions that use proper parsers, and it's good to know that Perl's `Time::Piece` handles dates before Epoch gracefully -- gawk's `strftime` does not, as I found out. :P

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do this in pure BASH and avoid calling `system` or `getline` from awk:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -ra arr; do 
   [[ ${arr[1]} != "null" ]] && arr[1]=$(date -d "${arr[1]}" +%F)
   printf "%s\t%s\n" "${arr[0]}" "${arr[1]}"
done < file

1       1966-04-28
2       null
3       null
4       1987-06-30
```

Comment: Pure bash is nice, but you stil call the expensive "date" a lot of times. system() or |getline from awk are not expensive, there is no reason not to use them.

Comment: **system() or |getline from awk are not expensive** and `date` is expensive? FYI `getline` ends up calling date as many times as this BASH solution.

Comment: The difference between calling `date` from the shell or via `system` in awk isn't really the important thing here. The primary difference between this approach and the currently accepted answer is that you're using a `while read` loop to read a file, instead of awk, so this is probably going to be slower if anything.

Comment: @TomFenech: No, I never really claimed this will be faster (but still think it won't be slower than awk). I just replied to a wrong assumption that this solution is calling `date` command more than the `awk` solution.

Comment: @TomFenech: I ran a quick test using `time` and this solution always ran way faster than `awk` and I can sense why. `awk` has to run `while` loop internally also to loop through the file and BASH is lower level language than awk so code might seem doing more in BASH but it is faster.

Comment: @anubhava interesting - how big is the input that you have tested with?

Comment: It wasn't a big one, just 400 lines. I can make it bigger but I suspect result will remain same.

Comment: But difference is huge for 400 lines. BASH took `0m5.345s` and awk took `0m24.405s`

Answer (score 0):

Only **one** date call and no code injection problem is possible, see the following:

This script extracts the dates (using awk) into a temporary file processes them with one "date" call and merges the results back (using awk).

### Code

```
awk -F '\t' 'match($3,/null/) { $3 = "0000-01-01" } { print $3 }' input > temp.$$
date --file=temp.$$ +%F > dates.$$
awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' 'BEGIN {
                           while ( getline < "'"dates.$$"'" > 0 )
                           {
                              f1_counter++
                              if ($0 == "0000-01-01") {$0 = "null"}
                              date[f1_counter] = $0
                           }
                         }
                         {$3 = date[NR]}
                         1' input.$$
```

**One-liner** using bash process redirections (no temporary files):

```
inputfile=/path/to/input
awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' 'BEGIN {while ( getline < "'<(date -f <(awk -F '\t' 'match($3,/null/) { $3 = "0000-01-01" } { print $3 }' "$inputfile") +%F)'" > 0 ){f1_counter++; if ($0 == "0000-01-01") {$0 = "null"}; date[f1_counter] = $0}}{$3 = date[NR]}1' "$inputfile"
```

### Details

here is how it can be used:

```
# configuration
input=/path/to/input
temp1=temp.$$
temp2=dates.$$
output=output.$$
# create the sample file (optional)
#printf "\t%s\n" $'1\t28 April 1966' $'2\tnull' $'3\tnull'  $'4\t30 June 1987' > "$input"
# Extract all dates
awk -F '\t' 'match($3,/null/) { $3 = "0000-01-01" } { print $3 }' "$input" > "$temp1"
# transform the dates
date --file="$temp1" +%F > "$temp2"
# merge csv with transformed date
awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' 'BEGIN {while ( getline < "'"$temp2"'" > 0 ){f1_counter++; if ($0 == "0000-01-01") {$0 = "null"}; date[f1_counter] = $0}}{$3 = date[NR]}1' "$input" > "$output"
# print the output
cat "$output"
# cleanup
rm "$temp1" "$temp2" "$output"
#rm "$input"
```

### Caveats

- Using "0000-01-01" as a temporary placeholder for invalid (null) dates
- The code **should** be faster than other methods calling "date" a lot of times, but it reads the input file two times.